# Running into the error "Opportunity must have a primary quote in order to create an order." when renewing contracts from Apex

Tags: apex, quote, cpq, order, contracts

Here is the code that we can run in Developer console to reproduce the error. What this code does:

1. Renews the expiring contract by setting the CPQ renewal fields to TRUE.
2. Queries the renewal opportunity created and creates order from it by
   setting `SBQQ__Ordered__c` to TRUE.
3. Queries the renewal quote created and creates contract from it by
   setting `SBQQ__Contracted__c` to TRUE.

If I do these DMLs in separate transactions, the error is gone but if I do these in same transaction this error comes up. I am not sure if I can build a solution around it if I don't know what I am waiting for it and how long I need to wait for it.

This is the code that you can run in developer console to reproduce the error.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//This code block creates renewal opportunity and quote.
Contract contractObj = [SELECT  Id,
                                SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c,
                                SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c,
                                SBQQ__RenewalTerm__c 
                        FROM    Contract 
                        WHERE   SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c = False 
                        AND     EndDate = TODAY 
                        LIMIT   1];
contractObj.SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c = true;
contractObj.SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c = true;
contractObj.SBQQ__RenewalTerm__c = 12;
update contractObj;

//This code block creates order from the renewal opportunity created above.
Id oppId = [SELECT  SBQQ__RenewalOpportunity__c 
            FROM    Contract 
            WHERE   Id =: contractObj.Id].SBQQ__RenewalOpportunity__c;
Opportunity oppObj = new Opportunity(Id = oppId,SBQQ__Ordered__c = True);
update oppObj;

//This code block creates contract from the renewal quote created above.
Id quoteId = [SELECT    SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__c 
                FROM    Opportunity 
                WHERE   Id=:oppId].SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__c;
Order orderObj = [SELECT    Id, 
                            SBQQ__Contracted__c 
                    FROM    Order 
                    WHERE   SBQQ__Quote__c =: quoteId];
orderObj.SBQQ__Contracted__c = true;
update orderObj;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I opened case with Salesforce and they suggested me to introduce delay between these code blocks to get around this error but that doesn't seem like a proper solution.

Has anyone found a better solution for this?

Comment: the hypothesis to check is that the act of `update contractObj` causes CPQW to do some work asynchronously that isn't completed before you do `updateOrderObj`. If yes, you'll need to restructure your application to take this into account. Debug log will help identify if there are async transactions involved

Comment: @cropredy Yes, it is doing some asynchronous process but I don't have a way to know when it finishes, because I don't have a id to check in `AsyncApexJob` object.

Comment: but you do have a way of querying/testing/retrying the field `SBQQ__Primary__c` on the renewal opportunity, no? Say, a chained series of queueables.  You could look at one of the several gitub apex promise libraries for a pattern to exploit

Comment: @cropredy Yes, I did a similar solution but using custom object to store these records and a scheduled apex job, which process these records.